# Execute only one query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables core_skills, life_skills and com_skills.
How can we search all three table data by executing only one query?
Only studentId is common in all three tables.

Code:

```
select studentid  from core_skills  where skills_name='XYZ';
```

Please help me including another two tables?

Comment: Give us more information. From what you said though, I suspect you want to use joins. Take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: @chandrakala kushwaha do you got with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
select * from from core_skills cs,
com_skills css,
life_skills ls 
where cs.student_id=css.student_id
and cs.student_id=ls.student_id 
and cs.skill_name='XYZ'
```